# How to create a zip file with password

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We use MFF 8.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3, and need to make an Java adapter which returns a zip file protected by password. Standard Java library does not provide function to create password-protected zip file. So we are thinking the following two approach,

1. Use OSS Java library, such as Zip4j
2. Call zip command provided with RedHat Enterprise Linux. 
   For this,  ProcessBuilder class start()/waitFor() methods will be used.

Zip file created by this adapter includes only one text(csv) file which size might be 10MB-100MB. 
Which way is better for a MFF adapter implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the two options, I would say Zip4j is a better option. Eventhough there is no MFP specific limitation using Linux Provided "Zip" via Process Builder, It introduces unnecessary dependency with  a specific environment.

Also, I see that you seem to be expecting large files (100 MB?) as zip output. You might want to review Figure 3. Protecting a resource on an external server” from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_oauth_security_model.html
if Large file transfers are involved.